# Retrieve LinkedIn access token

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get linkedIn oauth2 access token but I stuck on making last request to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken

```
const body = new URLSearchParams([
  ['grant_type', 'authorization_code'],
  ['code', code],
  ['redirect_uri', 'http://localhost:3000/'],
  ['client_id', CLIENT_ID],
  ['client_secret', CLIENT_SECRET]
]);
const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded'}); 

window.fetch('https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken', method: 'POST',body, headers)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
// rest of code
})
```

LinkedIn returns

> Fetch API cannot load https: //www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http: //localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

so I tried to make request in 'no-cors' mode. I've got 200 but I can't get body of response,status is 0, body is null and response.json() throws SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who came across this problem. We solved it by passing data from LinkedIn (code) to our backend. Backend have no need to send any preflight OPTIONS requests and can get access token without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out your issue,
The `Content-Type` header value is not correct.

It's meant to be

`const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});`

**NOT**

`const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded'});`

DOCS: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2 (Step 3)

Comment: It still doesn't work. 
Failed to load https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
And if I add header {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'} it fails on preflight...